# How to use C++11 thread with instance method?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a Class Player, and some sub-Class Player1, Player2, Player3 extends Player using C++.
Class Player have a method "run", and all of Player1,2,3 will override "run" to do different things.

```
class Player {
public:
    virtual void run();
}
class Player1: public Player {
public:
    void run();
}
```

In "main" function I will create some instance of Player1,2,3
and some C++11 thread call method "run" of these instance.

```
int main() {
    Player1 player1;
    Player2 player2;
    Player3 player3;
    Thread thread1(player1.run, this);
    Thread thread2(player2.run, this);
    Thread thread3(player3.run, this);
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried and I know it doesn't work,
so I try to use another function to call instance method.

```
function doRun1(Player1 player){
    player.run();
}

int main() {
    Player1 player1;
    Player2 player2;
    Player3 player3;
    Thread thread1(doRun1, player1);
    Thread thread2(doRun2, player2);
    Thread thread3(doRun3, player3);
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

This way seems to solve problem, but I have to create doRun1, doRun2, doRun3.... lots of function,
because the parameter of doRun1,2,3 need to be declare which is Player1,2 or 3

I can't think any better solution, can someone help me @@?

Comment: What does C11 have to do with this? What exactly is `Thread`, what's the signature for that constructor?

Comment: Wow. Does C11 have classes too?

Comment: Sorry, my fault... I knew what is this question@@. I means C++11 not C11, I will correct it... forgive me

Comment: `void main` is illegal. Please use `int main`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for something like this...

```
class Player {
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class Player1: public Player {
public:
    void run(); // you must implement then for Player1, 2, 3
};

void doRun(Player * player)
{
    player->run();
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Player1 player1;
    Player2 player2;
    Player3 player3;

    thread thread1(doRun, &player1);
    thread thread2(doRun, &player2);
    thread thread3(doRun, &player3);

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

If you prefer, you can also use lambda expressions:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Player1 player1;
    Player2 player2;
    Player3 player3;

    thread thread1([&] (Player * player) { player->run(); }, &player1);
    thread thread2([&] (Player * player) { player->run(); }, &player2);
    thread thread3([&] (Player * player) { player->run(); }, &player3);

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Or, following DyP suggestion:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Player1 player1;
    Player2 player2;
    Player3 player3;

    thread thread1(&Player::run, player1);
    thread thread2(&Player::run, player2);
    thread thread3(&Player::run, player3);

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the threads will run on *copies* of `player1`, `player2`, `player3`. If reference semantics are desired, `std::reference_wrappers` are a good option (passing `std::ref(player1)` etc). Also, `main` should return `int`.

Comment: Why not just `thread thread1(&Player::run, player1);`? (A pointer to a virtual member function still allows dynamic dispatch.)

Comment: you are right Dyp... much better than my quick solution... I will edit  to improve the answer. I just followed the `doRun()` he created so I kept it... but in fact the original wish is just to call the `Player::run()` ;-)

Comment: Just be careful about that last example, as it is taking a copy of the arguments, which means each new thread is taking a copy of each player subclass object.  This may or may not be what is desired.

Answer (score 4):

What you're ACTUALLY looking for is `std::bind`

```
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    Player1 myPlayer1;

    thread thread1(bind(&Player1::run, &myPlayer1));
}
```

What you're doing is creating a `std::function` object, which the `thread` constructor accepts.  Then you're "baking in" the instance as part of the `bind` function.  But be REALLY careful with this, as when myPlayer1 goes out of scope, that pointer does too.  You may want this instead:

```
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    shared_ptr<Player1> ptr_myPlayer1(new Player1());

    thread thread1(bind(&Player1::run, ptr_myPlayer1));
}
```

This allows the lifetime of the object to be the lifetime of the thread, not the lifetime of `main`.  That's not an issue in your trivial example, but it's an issue in real life.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) for more information on bind, and read the whole section on `functional` too.

Edit:

Combining what was said above about dynamic dispatch, this is also possible:

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    shared_ptr<Player> ptr_myPlayer(new Player1());  // Works because holds a pointer to base class

    thread thread1(&Player::run, ptr_myPlayer1);
}
```

This way you're using the virtual function of the base class, but you're using a smart pointer to a sub-class instance so you can exit the original function (assuming not main and the program isn't ending).  Best of all worlds.  `bind` isn't necessary here (since `std::thread` is already doing this internally, at least that's one possible implementation) but it's still on the general idea of "function pointer to anything" that the OP is wanting.